# Regex help, subset based on nth occurance from the end of string

Tags: r, regex

An example vector:

```
string <- "Junk1_Junk2_Junk3__ID1_Junk4_Junk5.pdf"
```

I am trying to subset `ID1` by counting `_` (underscores) from the right; so subset between the second and 3rd underscore from the right.

expected output: `ID1`

My attempt was to try to use the double `__`,
but this is not going to work, because not all my string list has it.

Attempt: `(_){2}([^_]+)`

Side note, I am trying to get comfortable with regex; please recommend a resource to build and test.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected result?.

Comment: Edited the post: expected result = `'ID1'`

Comment: A quick shot: `gsub("(.*?_){3}(.*)(_.*?){2}.*", "\\2", string)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(string, "[^_]+(?=(?:_[^_]*){2}$)")
```

Or, same approach with base R:

```r
## Base R:
sub(".*?([^_]+)(?:_[^_]*){2}$", "\\1", string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mFHB24/1/) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/RlMsmL).

*Details*:

- `[^_]+` - one or more chars other than `_`
- `(?=(?:_[^_]*){2}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires two sequences of `_` and then zero or more repetitons of any char other than `_` till the end of string
- `.*?([^_]+)(?:_[^_]*){2}$` matches

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as  possible
  - `([^_]+)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to this captured string): one or more chars other than `_`
  - `(?:_[^_]*){2}` - two sequences of `_` and then zero or more repetitons of any char other than `_`
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Very nice.  Could use this slight variation to better allow multiple _ as a delimiter `[^_]+(?=(?:_+[^_]+){2}$)`

Comment: @Daniel Yes, `+` means *one or more* and `*` means *zero or more*. Use as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub(".*_([^_]+)(_[^_]+){2}", "\\1", string)
[1] "ID1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought about doing this in pure Regex, but I think I would actually simplify this problem in R. I'm going to use some very simple regex and two R commands instead of 1.

```
str_extract(string,"[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+$") %>% 
  str_remove("_[^_]+_[^_]+$")
```

Here I'm finding a combo of not-underscores `[^_]+` and underscores `_`.

For ease of Regex I'm extracting the whole string. Then I remove the excess.

Alternatively, we can use a bit more complex Regex with the lookahead method.

```
str_extract(string,"[^_]+(?=_[^_]+_[^_]+$)")
```

I think the lookahead code is a bit more advanced to read for many coders that don't use Regex a lot.